# Declaring a variable containing a path

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I am trying to put a path d (M119.848,98, that sort of thing) into a variable.

I have this:

```
d2 = 'M119.848,98.534
    c112.231-33.453,258.264-6.625,533.98-82.285s670.648,195.214,617.699,245.323s-125.469,301.377-633.456,79.442
    s-414.501-55.838-554.989-37.641C-57.406,321.569,7.617,131.987,119.848,98.534z';
```

Seems like a really lame question, but why is it giving me an error? I guess some of the dots or commas, but it is a bit strange since all of this is in a string.

Also, what would be the most appropriate way to change the path in Snap.svg? I am thinking of changing the d attribute on a click event..

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, if you want to type in one string using multiple lines, you must place the `\` tag at the end of each line.

```
d2 = 'M119.848,98.534\
c112.231-33.453,258.264-6.625,533.98-82.285s670.648,195.214,617.699,245.323s-125.469,301.377-633.456,79.442\
s-414.501-55.838-554.989-37.641C-57.406,321.569,7.617,131.987,119.848,98.534z';
```

Note that this will not be interpreted by the javascript compiler as one continuous string - not a string containing line feeds. If you want to insert an actual line feed into your string, type `\n`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the problem is that it doesn't contain only numbers, but letters as well.

Comment: @Georgi B. Nikolov - OK, updated to talk about multi-line strings.

Comment: @Georgi B. Nikolov - You're welcome. If this helped you, please press the tick button next to this question.